# padding of text view being applied to other views in linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the below item layout for my list view. What i expect is the second TextView(txt_time) to appear a little below and to the right of the first TextView(txt_chat). But both appear on the same vertical space next to each other. I tried adding a bottom padding to the first TextView, but it made the second one also move automatically upwards to stay in line with the first TextView. Is there something else i can try?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id ="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_green"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_chat"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:paddingBottom="20px"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_time"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="test"
            android:paddingBottom="0px"
            />

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is what i am trying to achieve :

[image]

Comment: Does `px` works???? Use `dp` or `dip`, instead of `px`.

Comment: Try Ralative layout instead of Linear layout

Comment: see my answer it will look exactly as you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the various answers posted had good solutions, no single solution resolved the complete problem. So i have combined it into one answer here. Thanks for the answers.

use this layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id ="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_green"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_chat"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_time"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="test"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            />

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Points to note :**

1. Use margins instead of padding.
2. Use `layout_marginBottom` for `txt_chat` with a parent `LinearLayout`. Using it with `RelativeLayout` will have no effect.
3. Use `layout_gravity="bottom"` for `txt_time` so that it does not move upwards when multi line text is input in `txt_chat`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Use `dp or dip`, instead of `px` into padding. And replace the below views with existing..

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_chat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="20dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:text="test" />
```

Comment: did not make any difference other than a little increase in the padding.

Comment: Share sketch about how the view should aligned.

Comment: thanks. that worked. But i was hoping for the top margin of txt_time to be a few dp above the bottom margin of txt_chat. Right now, both these margins are aligned.

Comment: Using margins instead of padding worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from your question how the textviews should be aligned. As far as I understood you want something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esSk2.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id ="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_chat"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_time"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_chat"
        />

        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was hoping the top of "ProgressBar" to start somewhere around the middle of "Hello world!"

Comment: @faizal check the image now in my answer.

Comment: When there is multiple lines of input in txt_chat, then txt_time moves upwards. Is there a way to keep txt_time anchored to the bottom?

Comment: Try using `android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txt_chat"` inside `txt_time`.

Comment: i had to use layout_marginBottom for txt_chat and a parent Linear layout to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

how could you use `padding` property to get space between `childviews`

**`padding`** is used to get space inside the view.

Instead of `padding` you should use **`margin`** property to get space between your views..

use below code in second `textView`

```
    marginTop = "20dp"
    marginLeft = "10dp"
```

Following code maybe useful  for you..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id ="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_chat"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Hello"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_time"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

this may help you..

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfectly. But when there is multiple lines of input in txt_chat, then txt_time moves upwards. Is there a way to keep txt_time anchored to the bottom?

Comment: i had to use layout_marginBottom for txt_chat and layout_gravity="Bottom" for txt_time to resolve this.

Comment: I tried relative layout as in @Aniruddha's solution, but that had the same issue. So i reverted back to Linear Layout. As long as the issue is resolved, the kind of layout does not matter to me. I have posted an answer with the final solution. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving `paddingBottom` to 1st`TextView` give `paddingTop` to 2nd `textView`

Try following data :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id ="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_chat"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="first text"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_time"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="test"
           android:paddingTop="20dp"
            />

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it works

Comment: That's interesting. Now txt_time has moved exactly below txt_chat. How would i make txt_time move to the right as well? i.e. the left margin of txt_time should be aligned with right margin of txt_chat.

Comment: What do u mean by "left margin of txt_time should be aligned with right margin of txt_chat" ?? U want your both texts to be on left and right corners ???

Comment: I have added a pic in the OP to illustrate what i mean. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **px** use **dp**

```
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

please add **android:layout_gravity="bottom"** to the last textview. Hope this works

and if you want it full screen width use the below xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id ="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble_green"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_chat"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:paddingBottom="20px"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_time"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:paddingBottom="0px"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```